# Using infinite scroll for rendering and fetching more data using react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-infinite-scroll-component

I wanted to add an infinite scroll component to one of my react components.
I am using `react-infinite-scroll-component` and want to add fetch more after a certain length.

Here is the component and I want to make an Infinite scroll on new Items

```
let newItems = logs.filter(function(log){
        return log.completed === false
    })
    return (
        <div>
            <div>
            <h1>ALL</h1>
            {
                newItems.map((item)=>(
                    <Item key={item.id} logs={logs} />
                )  
                )
            }
        </div>
        </div>
```

The code snippet provided in `react-infinite-scroll-component`  [examples](https://codesandbox.io/s/yk7637p62z) I want to achieve similar with 5 elements from newItems list.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem. In the example you linked you can change the two instances of `20` to `5` and change the height of the items so it will trigger the infinite scroll for example.

Comment: Basically I have a list of items in newItems and I want to view them inside a div, lets say initially in that div the newItems has 5 items inside it and I want to show only 2 when the user will scroll down automatically 3 more will be fetched from newItems. I want to do this through real-infinite-scroll-component and provided the link to one of the examples the package mentioned.

Comment: But like I said can't you just change the initial state to an array of five and change how many items are retrieved in your fetch call to only add 3?